# How can I authenticate users on Ignite Openfire against my MongoDB instance that contains users?

Tags: mongodb, xmpp, openfire

I have an Ignite Openfire XMPP server set up, I also have a MongoDB instance that contains users which I am using for another aspect of the application. Is it possible to set up Openfire to use my MongoDB instance for authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure you will have to create your own [AuthProvider](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/openfire/auth/AuthProvider.html) since the built in DB provider is JDBC based (which I assume doesn't work with MongoDB, but that is an assumption).

I haven't done it, but I would guess it isn't that hard to do. The interface is fairly simple.